# How do I use a field name with characters (hyphen, period and colon) in MongoDB queries?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this: `{ _id: 0, x: { y: { "15-8:6.1": 200 } } }`

I want to use something like the following, and is it possible?

```
var fld = "x.y.15-8:6.1";
db.test.findOne( { fld : 200 } 
db.test.updateOne( { _id: 0 }, { $set : { fld : 999 } } )
```

I have searched a little bit and mostly find it can't be done.

Comment: I don't think it can be done. From [mongodb limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names): *"The MongoDB Query Language cannot always meaningfully express queries over documents whose field names contain these characters. Until support is added in the query language, the use of $ and . in field names is not recommended and is not supported by the official MongoDB drivers"*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is mongo specific, but with a JavaScript approach, since the `findOne` function expects an object you could construct it as follows:

```
var fldName = "x.y.15-8:6.1";
var query = {};
query[fldName] = 200;
db.test.findOne(query);
```

I would recommend doing some sanity checks on the actual field name you are using. Since this is a dynamic query you might not be updating the field you intended. Having safeguards in place that would ensure (for example) that `fldName` is not empty, or that it's value is in an expected format would reduce the risk of overriding something unintentionally.